# How can i return response only if one methodcall is completed in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, promise

I have a node js with express application. I need to expose a rest endpoint that will return the response of a http call. Whatever I try it returns before the http request. Can you please help

```
app.all('/query', function(req, res){
  // here i need to make a http call 
    let urlCall =   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get('http://test.com', (response) => {
            let sdata = '';

            response.on('data', (fragments) => {
              sdata += fragments;
            });
        
            response.on('end', () => {
              let response_body = sdata;
              resolve(response_body.toString());
            });
        
            response.on('error', (error) => {
            // promise rejected on error
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
    urlCall.then((response) => {
        var responseData=response;
        res.json(responseData);
        res.end();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: why do you use `new Promise`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but I suspect a request error not being handled (the error event handler being missing on your request)

You can try moving the error handler from the response to the request

```js
app.all("/query", function (req, res) {
  // here i need to make a http call

  let urlCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http
      .get("http://test.com", (response) => {
        let sdata = "";

        response.on("data", (fragments) => {
          sdata += fragments;
        });

        response.on("end", () => {
          let response_body = sdata;
          resolve(response_body.toString());
        });
      })
      .on("error", (error) => { // handling request errors
        console.error("error");
        // promise rejected on error
        reject(error);
      });
  });

  urlCall.then(
    (response) => {
      res.json(response);
      res.end();
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.end();
    }
  );
});
```